# Convert a List<StringBuilder> to List<String> java using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there a way to convert a `List<StringBuilder>` to `List<String>` using Java Streams? Is there an easy way to typecast it ?

Comment: there is no way to type cast it... just use a `map(StringBuilder::toString)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just map it:

```
list.stream().map(StringBuilder::toString).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Ofc you can also use a more general method reference, e.g. `Object::toString`; doesn't make much difference, though.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
public List<String> convert(List<StringBuilder> builders) {
    return builders.stream().map(StringBuilder::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: If you propose a method, at least make it generic :)

Comment: guys, for real ? :)

Comment: @jaudo you don’t need to make it generic, just change the parameter to `List<?>` and `StringBuilder::toString` to `Object::toString`…